# Do sneak bonus damage modifiers affect magical/elemental and poison damage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I sneak and get a double damage strike on a target with:

- A sword with 10 fire damage
- A sword with an applied poison of 15 damage

Does only the base damage have the bonus, or does every damage type receive it too?