# Does magic damage add on to a weapon's damage or is it a part of it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If a weapon has 26 damage, and does 10 fire damage to the target, is it
(16 base damage) + (10 magic damage) = (26 total damage), or
(26 base damage) + (10 magic damage) = (36 total damage)?

Also, what if it has absorb health? Does that act the same way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Magic Effects and poison are calculated independant of the base damage of the weapon. The number listed on the weapon is the base damage *only* and does not consider any enchantments or poisons applied.

As [previously established on this site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39867/sneak-damage-multiplier-does-it-apply-to-magical-damage-too/39868#39868), only the base damage of the weapon gets multiplied by things like crits.